# QWebView - Error 400 when giving url

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, qt4, pyqt4, boto

I'm trying to build a little application that needs to run the url that is generated by the script at this link: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx70F69I9G8TYG/How-to-enable-cross-account-access-to-the-AWS-Management-Console

The application is build with Qt4 and Pyqt4. I create a QWebView and want to load the url that is generated at the end of the script in the link inside the webview.

```
url =  QUrl(ConnectionScript.generateURL())
self.webView.load(url)
self.webView.show()
```

but this code gives me a "HTTP Status 400 - BadRequest" error. I've tried to change the "load" with "setUrl" but there is no change.

The useful code is only this, other lines are just setting up the GUI (and it's doing fine). Any suggestion about how to fix this and what might the problem be? I think it's something very easy to fix but i can't do it right...

Edit1: i forgot to mention that when i open the generated link in a web browser (like chrome or firefox) all goes well and it gives me no such error

Comment: `Error 400` stands for bad request in `HTTP`. So I assume that the `url` is not ok. When you call `self.webView.url()` is the returned `url` the one you actually want to load?

Comment: Yes, just plain same and it works in a web browser too if i copy/paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was this line of code:

```
request_parameters += urllib.quote_plus("https://console.aws.amazon.com/")
```

The quote_plus encoded : / so the webView load couldn't process the url in the right way.
Just don't use the urllib.quote_plus method and everything will go as expected.